# Obtener consulta select y output param SQL en c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedure

Buen día

Estoy tratando de realizar una consulta a un sp en SQL server el cual me retorna un parámetro de nombre @Total(que tiene el total de registros en la tabla) y una consulta select filtrada

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Task_GetAllAndConutStatus] 
    @Total INT = 0 OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
        SELECT 
                    Id,
                    Nombre,
                    Descripcion,
                    CreatedAt,
                    UpdatedAt,
                    DeletedAt,
                FROM
                    Task
                WHERE 
                    [DeletedAt] IS NULL

        SELECT 
                @Total = COUNT(*)
                FROM
                    Task
                WHERE 
                    OnGoin ='S' AND [DeletedAt] IS NULL
        SELECT @Total;
    
END
GO
```

Y en c# estoy tratando de obtener el valor @Total y el select, tengo el problema que si me retorna la conusulta del select pero el parametro ***@Total*** siempre se queda en cero, este es mi código:

```
public RespuestaTask Task_GetAllAndConutStatus()
        {
     RespuestaTask  Respuesta = new RespuestaTask ();
            try
            {
                using (var con = GetConeccionString(TaskConfiguration.ConexionString))
                {
                    if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                        con.Open();
                    #region Registros
                    var query = new SqlCommand(StoreProcedures.Task_GetAllAndConutStatus,con)
                    {
                        CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
                    };
                    var totalParam = new SqlParameter("@Total", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
                    totalParam.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
                    query.Parameters.Add(totalParam);
                    
                    SqlDataReader reader = query.ExecuteReader();
                    Respuesta.List = new List<Task>();
                    if (reader != null && reader.HasRows)
                        while (reader.Read())
                            Respuesta.List.Add(BuildModel(reader));
                    #endregion
                    #region Número de registros
                    Respuesta.Row = Convert.ToInt32(query.Parameters["@Total"].Value);
                    reader.Close();                    
                    #endregion
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                RegistrarExcepcion(ref Respuesta, ex);
            }
            return Respuesta;
        }
```

Saludos

Comment: probaste que el procedimiento te devuelva algo en el SqlServer?

Comment: Si de echo me retorna un listado con 15 de las cuales total son 15 con ese estatus y en SQL muestra tanto el listado como el total

Answer (score 0):

intentalo de la siguiente manera

```
        SqlConnectData connection = new SqlConnectData(connectionString);
        using (connection.conn)
        {
            connection.conn.Open();
            var command = new SqlDataAdapter(StoreProcedures.Task_GetAllAndConutStatus, connection.conn);
            command.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Total", SqlDbType.Int, int.MaxValue).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            command.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
           Respuesta.Row = Convert.ToInt32(command.SelectCommand.Parameters["@Total"].Value);;
            connection.conn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: PEro eso, no le va a devolver el query.. solo el total....

Comment: Si , intente eso pero solo devuelve el parametro mas no el query y si ocupo los dos

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo pude obtener, al parecer cuando quieres usar los dos requieres cerrar el DataReader para continuar con los parametros lo encontre en esta liga:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32052621/possible-to-return-an-out-parameter-with-a-datareader

Gracias